# NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: delay enumeration

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I use fast enumeration and in the enumeration block I send network requests asynchronously.

So what happens is the enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: just call the block super fast and let the enumeration block finish after some time.

This leads to different results, because some requests finish faster than other. So it's not sorted as I wanted.

Is there any way to set the block to freeze, and after the asynchronous network requests is completed, to just tell it to go to the next one?

Here is some code

```
    NSArray *sites = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects copy];
    NSLog(@"sites - %@",sites);
    [sites enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Sites *site, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"site name - %@,",site.name);

        [[Wrapper sharedWrapper] sendRequestTo:site completionBlock:{

                NSLog(@"site name - %@",site.name);
        }];
    }];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Fast enumeration and enumeration using blocks is not the same. Please post some code for context and it will be much easier to help you

Comment: What about the async network requests? Where do they come in?

Comment: You're using an asynchronous enumerator to enumerate and read NSManagedObjects.... not something you want to do ... ever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to set the block to freeze, and after the asynchronous network requests is completed, to just tell it to go to the next one?

You can achieve that result by reorganizing your code: instead of using enumeration, just execute the async request from the completion block, one at the time:

```
- (void) doRequestAsync:(NSArray*)sites index:(NSUInteger)index {

    if (index >= [sites count]) return;

    NSString* site = [sites objectAtIndex:index];
    [[Wrapper sharedWrapper] sendRequestTo:site completionBlock:{
            NSLog(@"site name - %@",site.name);
            [self doRequestAsync:sites index:++index];
    }];

}
```

Alternatives to this are modifying your `Wrapper` class so that it uses async networking (but use it on a secondary thread, then, to avoid blocking the UI).

Or you might implement the [Async Completion Token pattern](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/ACT.pdf) so to be able to reorder the responses when they are received.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to set the block to freeze, and after the
>   asynchronous network requests is completed, to just tell it to go to
>   the next one?

```
NSArray *sites = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects copy];
NSLog(@"sites - %@",sites);
[sites enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Sites *site, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"site name - %@,",site.name);
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    [[Wrapper sharedWrapper] sendRequestTo:site completionBlock:{

            NSLog(@"site name - %@",site.name);
dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}];
```

^ Not really the ideal way to do this but if you want to synchronously iterate while waiting for an async request to finish before moving forward, the above will do it via GCD. There are other ways to to where you can iterate and increment a dispatch_group while waiting for all the groups to be left after the async tasks complete such as:

```
dispatch_group_t downloadGroup = dispatch_group_create();


        dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup);
        [self fetchStuffInBackground:background withCompletion:^(NSArray *stuff, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"leaving stuff");
            dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup);
        }];
        dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup);
        [self fetchAOtherStuffInBackground:background withCompletion:^(NSArray *stuff, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"leaving other stuff");
            dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup);
        }];
              dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup);
        [self fetchLastStuffInBackground:background withCompletion:^(NSArray *lastStuff, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"leaving last stuff");
            dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup);
        }];      
    }

}
dispatch_group_notify(downloadGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (callback) {
        callback(error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to achieve the same thing but keep using blocks to simplify my code, instead of having the hassle of passing parameters through a recursive method. I came up with this NSArray category:

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface NSArray(MH)

- (void)mh_asyncEnumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL* stop, dispatch_block_t next))block;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

@implementation NSArray(MH)

- (void)mh_asyncEnumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL* stop, dispatch_block_t next))block{
    __block NSUInteger index = 0;
    __block BOOL stop = NO;

    void (^next)();
    __block __weak typeof(next) weakNext;
    weakNext = next = ^void() {
        void (^strongNext)() = weakNext;
        // check if finished
        if(stop || index == self.count){
            return;
        }
        id obj = self[index];
        index++;
        block(obj, index - 1, &stop, strongNext);
    };
    next();
}

@end
```

It's used like this:

```
NSArray* a = @[@"Malc", @"Bob", @"Jim"];
[a mh_asyncEnumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop, dispatch_block_t next) {
    // simulate an async network call
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"%@", obj);
        next();
    });
}];
```

Output:

```
2016-01-04 22:41:04.631 Malc
2016-01-04 22:41:05.632 Bob
2016-01-04 22:41:06.720 Jim
```

As you can see, this demo outputs each string in the array with 1 second delay. You can use it by doing your network call inside the block and then calling next when it's done. If you hit an error and would like to cancel just set *stop = YES; before calling next(), the same as you would do with normal enumeration.

```
NSArray *sites = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects copy];
NSLog(@"sites - %@",sites);
[sites mh_asyncEnumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Site *site, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop, dispatch_block_t next){
    NSLog(@"site name - %@,",site.name);

    [[Wrapper sharedWrapper] sendRequestTo:site completionBlock:{
          if(error){ // your completion block should have an error param!!!
              *stop = YES;
          }
          NSLog(@"site name - %@",site.name);
          next();
     }];
 }];
```